# Crack the pigeon code

Tags: cipher, unsolved-mysteries

**Can you crack this message?** It was [discovered in a chimney in 2012 attached to a carrier pigeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Pigeon_Service#Pigeon_NURP_40_TW_194) and was most likely sent during the D-day invasions. The GCHQ was not able to crack it, even after opening it up to the public. There is still hope, but the code may never be broken...

```
AOAKN     HVPKD     FNFJU     YIDDC
RQXSR     DJHFP     GOVFN     MIAPX
PABUZ     WYYNP     CMPNW     HJRZH
NLXKG     MEMKK     ONOIB     AKEEQ
UAOTA     RBQRH     DJOFM     TPZEH
LKXGH     RGGHT     JRZCQ     FNKTQ
KLDTS     GQIRU     AOAKN   27 1525/6
```

[image: The message found on the pigeon]

Comment: Just to clarify -- is this a real thing found on a real dead carrier pigeon that real cryptographers have spent weeks failing to solve? Or is it a puzzle you've created that has that as a sort of "framing story"? [EDITED to add:] the "weeks" bit refers to text that is no longer in the question.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan it sounds like this is a [real thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Pigeon_Service). I have added the "unsolved mysteries" tag.

Comment: The codes are exactly as the paged linked by @Hugh which quotes [GCHQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_Communications_Headquarters): "without access to the original code books, details of any additional encryption, or any context around the message, it will be impossible to decode. Similarly it means that any proposed solutions sent to GCHQ will, without such material, be impossible to prove correct."

Comment: can we hold it up to a mirror?

Comment: Look guys I am just a question asker . I don’t know much about this question even though I did a lot of research,I couldn’t get any sort of information or trace that could give hints or accuracy, so now be the first to crack it ... Hve a nice day

Comment: @Hugh thank you for adding tag (unsolved mystery)

Comment: my guess is that a second pigeon carried the key to decypher this. but i may be wrong

Comment: @Flying_whale good try . Keep thinking,may be you can be the first to answer this mysterious question. Every one is new here

Comment: Perhaps [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] could also be included here? ;)

Comment: Could easily be some co-ordinates list. Seeing as the pigeon was specifically intended for a destination, the receiving side would know what to apply it to. The letters could be a grid that the numeric key is applied to

Comment: @nine9      Ya sounds good but I not sure, try your best , that was really a good approach

Comment: I donno know what that number over right bottom doing, may be a date?

Comment: WEEKS?  This code is DECADES old. https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-20456782

It definitely belongs here, but it certainly shouldn't be misrepresented.

Comment: Thanks for supporting guys if want I can place some more bounty

Comment: https://www.seeker.com/can-you-crack-the-pigeons-code-1766090100.html  Could help you a bit

Comment: GCHQ says The first group of letters indicated the bird's origin ("NURP" stands for National Union of Racing Pigeons), while the following two-digit number attested its year of registration (40 refers to 1940).The final set of numbers identified the specific pigeon and the area of the country it was from

Comment: are they all names of pigeons?

Comment: @user477343 no, I believe that tag is not appropriate in this case - we do know exactly what we are expected to do, namely, decrypt the encrypted message.

Comment: @Brandon_J But... wait... you're right. Whoops; my bad.

Comment: @user477343 hey, no problem :)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No.

Comment: Are the letters at the top of the third column FNFJU or FNFJW? The text and the image seem to disagree.